Add Public Name In Wallet Address
How do we add a "Public Name" like the example in the picture, to our Solana address? Sorry, I'm a beginner here.


That is done by Solscan in their backend. All major exchanges, wallets, and other important accounts are already labelled by Solscan developers, same goes for most other explorers like Solana.fm etc. as well.
On Solana blockchain, no wallet address has any human readable public name associated with it. You can however buy a SNS Domain which will get you a custom and public .sol domain which will be displayed in explorers and can be used in wallets to send/receive funds.
If you log into Solscan, then you can also assign such names for your own reference as well, but it won't be public to everyone else.
